# What is a notation for a "diagonal" on a globe?

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude

Is "diagonal" even the right word here?

We have latitude and longitude to create a sort of grid and when combined make a point.

Both latitude and longitude individually span a line around the globe at some slice of it.

With two latitude and longitude pairs we can define a diagonal based on the points created by both pairs.

Surely there is a way to express this diagonal? Maybe a specified way to express two pairs of lat/lon coordinates, or without using lat/lon?

Comment: The word you're looking for is probably "bearing".

Comment: In the sampling world, the line would be called a "transect". Bearing (angle) and distance could be calculated from the points using the Reverse, aka Inverse, Problem of [Geodesy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy) (Forward, aka Direct, is used to find point2 from point1/bearing/distance)